# capistrano is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm following the [this site](http://blog.sudobits.com/2013/01/07/how-to-deploy-rails-application-to-vps/).

And I'm getting error step 5(Setting up Capistrano for Deployment).

I just add following lines to buttom of `Gemfile` file.

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'
```

And typing this command.

```
$ bundle install
```

And typing this command too. By the way, I get some error.

```
$ capify .
The program 'capify' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install capistrano
```

So I just check bundle..

```
$ bundle show|grep capistrano
* capistrano (2.15.4)
```

Why I can't use command that is `capify .`?

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `bundle exec capify .` instead of `capify .`.